# streaming video android

Tags: android, video-streaming

Basically I am writing code for video player using media controller and videoview and is working well when i set videoview.setvideopath(string)...also When a play a mp3 file using mediaplayer.setsourcedata() it also work well........

my question is that i want to stream a video from SD card ...so that for i have to pass input stream to video view but it is not possible ...
when a play the same my passing a video stream to mediaplayer.setsourcedata() it work but only a sound come from mp4 file ,,,no video is displayed....

this is nice example

```
File clip=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                   "test.mp4");
  video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);
  video.setVideoPath(clip.getAbsolutePath());

  ctlr=new MediaController(this);
  ctlr.setMediaPlayer(video);
  video.setMediaController(ctlr);
  video.requestFocus();
  video.start();


//it work fine but "test.mp4" is a file and I want a stream of mp4 like 

InputStream in = null;
in = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(clip));

//and finally this stream has to be in video view...
```

If anybody as prior knowledge to video stream please help me out.

Comment: why do you want to buffer a video which is already available in your local?

Comment: Andro Selva- what I need is to stream the video in real time from sdcard. i have a video that should be encrypted and i want the video should be played in my player while decryption is done at run time then i will use file descriptor to play the stream ..

Comment: have u found the answer? i would love to know it too

Comment: Nop ,,yet yeah aftreward 2.2 you can use flash to stream video or else  you have to move to NDK ... it didnt do any ...